# Katalon Studio Authenticate Parameters Are Not Used Correctly

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, ui-testing, katalon-studio

I'm trying to use Katalon Studio to test a web application behind Basic Authentication. I've seen that I can use the Authenticate keyword for this but for some reason when I try to, and specify parameters that seem correct as far as I can glean from the documentation, it doesn't work as expected. It looks like the password parameter is being sent as the username and that "{2}" is being sent as the password.

[image: The step in the GUI]
[image: The step in code]
[image: The resulting message when the step is run]

Does anyone have any idea how I can deal with this, or what I could be doing wrong?